# Regex - Retrieving specific words in a pattern

Tags: python, regex

On Python, suppose that I have a **string**, that represent a pattern of strings, like that:

```
myString = "//command -name two -parent one [...]"
```

Where `[...]` means a sequence of *-arg* and *value*.

How can I extract a specific content from the string? 
For example, I would like to extract the words:

```
wordsExtracted = ['command', 'name', 'two', 'parent', 'one', ... ]
```

Where `...` means ... *you know what means!*

I think the best way to retrieve that is using **RegEx**, right? 
Another way is spliting using both '//' and '-', but I think this is not an ellegant way to do that.

So... How can I do what I want?

Comment: Maybe you mean something like `(?:your word)|(?:your_other_word)|(?:your_other_word)` or in that fashion.

Comment: Maybe, but I don't want to limit the amount of words.

Comment: Can't you just do `myString.split()`?

Comment: Yes, but it comes with '//' and '-'. RegEx could say to me if the string follow the pattern.

Comment: @Richard you can just generate a string based on that list with a simple split or loop (with certain rules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are other solutions, but if you want to use regular expressions, a pattern like this would work

```
\w+
```

This will match any sequence of one or more 'word' characters. (see the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for a precise definition)

For example:

```
import re
re.findall('\w+', myString)
=> ['command', 'name', 'two', 'parent', 'one']
```

To handle any other special characters that might occur within the parameters, you might want to use something like this:

```
[^\s/-]\S*
```

This will match any character that's not a whitespace character, hyphen, or forward slash, followed by zero or more non-whitespace characters.

For example:

```
myString = "//command -name two -parent one-one foo@example.com"
re.findall('[^\s/-]\S*', myString)
=> ['command', 'name', 'two', 'parent', 'one-one', 'foo@example.com']
```

Comment: it fails if an argument value contains `-` for example. `-opt I-am-kent`

Comment: @Kent That's a fair point, though I'm not sure that that's a requirement. Nevertheless, I've included that as an alternative

Comment: well, you fixed that `-` case. maybe I didn't make it clear in my last comment. the `\w` works great with the given example. however, it will fail if the value string contains `\W`, well `\s` in this case doesn't make sense, but we have still `-, :, .(dot)...` so I am not sure if `\w` is right for this problem.

Comment: @Kent is right, for example, this not work with a email address as part of string. It just split after and before '@'.

Comment: @Richard It would help if you specified a bit more about what exactly you wanted to match and what you didn't. However, see my updated answer for something that should work in most cases.

Comment: Sorry, Thank you for your updating.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are a possible solution, but I'd probably choose one of:

- http://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#module-shlex
- http://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

Comment: Not even an simple example?

Answer (score 0):

```
import shlex
myString = "//command -name two -parent one [...]"
shlex.split(myString)
['//command', '-name', 'two', '-parent', 'one', '[...]']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [11]: myString = "//command -name two -parent one -foo bar"

In [12]: [re.sub(u'^[-/]*', '', x) for x in myString.split()]
Out[12]: ['command', 'name', 'two', 'parent', 'one', 'foo', 'bar']
```

`import re` is needed.